# Oracle SQL Developer regex expression error

Tags: sql, regex, oracle-sqldeveloper

In the script file, I inserted the following code.

```
drop table Test;
create table Test(
name char(2) unique not null,
constraint name_c check(
regexp_like(name, '^[A-Z]{1,2}$', 'c')
)
);

insert into Test values ('B');
```

The developer never budge. It keeps on saying violating the name_c constraint and I don't understand why. The regular expression looks fine for me.

Some variants, however, succeeded, for example, dropping the dollar sign

```
drop table Test;
create table Test(
name char(2) unique not null,
constraint name_c check(
regexp_like(name, '^[A-Z]{1,2}', 'c')
)
);

insert into Test values ('B');
```

And I don't understand either.

Why?

Edit: This is the problem: logically the regex is right. But somehow Oracle SQL Developer doesn't budge.

[image]

Comment: What is intention here?  Do you want 1 or 2 capital letters, or just something which starts with 1 or 2 capital letters?

Comment: What are the differences? I assume start with 1 capital letter = want 1 capital letter, start with 2 capital letter = want 2 capital letters

Comment: That doesn't answer my question unfortunately.

Comment: Start with 1 capital letter or start with 2 capital letters. If it starts with 1 capital letter, then there should be nothing behind.

Comment: Then you want the second version.

Comment: Yes, the second.

Answer (score 0):

if you went it to start with 1 or 2 capital letter and doesn't matter what coming next you should do it like this :

```
^[A-Z]{1,2}.*
```

```
.* mean 1 or more character exept \n (nex line)
```

Comment: But I do care about what coming next. I want to start and end with exact letters. That is why I put dollar sign in the regular expression. And it doesn't work in oracle sql developer.

Comment: if you want only first letter upper case and the rest lower case then write it like this `^[A-Z]{1,1}[a-z]+.` else if you want first letter upper case and the rest either upper or lower then `^[A-Z]{1,1}[a-zA-Z]+` else if you want 1 or tow upper in the first then change `[A-Z]{1,1}` by `[A-Z]{1,2}` , i wish this help you

Comment: Sorry I was unfair. Yes the solution works. But I wonder, what happened with the dollar sign? I mean in this example the $ seems buggy.

Comment: $ sign mean match the end of text string or end of line in multiline case , and it use in case u went test for the last letter or you want to make all text match .Par example `^text$` that will test if the hole string match 'test' and in case `text$` this will test if string end with 'test' and in case `^text` his will test if string begin with 'test' in your exemple if name can be somting else in the end then you should add $ sign

Comment: `^[A-Z]{1,2}$`, in this expression, what I am saying is start and end with 2 capital letters. My question is: why does it not work? And why does it work after removing dollar sign. This troubles me the most.

Comment: as i tell `[A-Z]{1,2}` mean 1 or 2 upper case character and if you add `^ and $` this mean all text should be mean 1 or 2 upper case then if you have 'Aaa' will not work because 3 character in another case when you removing $ then only test if start with 1 or 2 upper case , in case of 'Aaa' this will be true because it start with one upper case letter

Comment: I understand and agree with you totally and logically. But in my Oracle SQL Developer, I don't know why but when I insert `'A'` under the constraint `^[A-Z]{1,2}$`. It keeps on telling me violation! This troubles me the most!!! (Edited, 1A)

Comment: i think it should work , try it here https://regexr.com/5f7l0

Comment: It doesn't when I try it in Oracle SQL Developer...

Comment: i think  the problem from this `{1,2}` maybe it always make 2 try like this `^[A-Z][A-Z]?$`

Comment: No, it still violated when I input `'A'`